# ngView Animation Enter not firing on first page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute, ng-animate

I've been struggling with a very subtle bug on my website for a few days, but couldn't find any solutions to it (maybe my knowledge in AngularJs is not enough)

I'm using latest angular (v1.6.1), ngRoute and ngAnimate.

The thing is that ngView animation enter is not firing when you go to website (when the website loads first time).

Here is my code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ngRoute']);

app.animation('.view', function () {
  return {
    enter : function (element, done) {
      alert('enter');
      done();
    },
    leave : function (element, done) {
      alert('leave');
      done();
    }
  }
});

//Config

app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider){

  $routeProvider.when('/test.php',{
    template : function () {
      return "<div>Welcome to test page</div>";
    }
  });
  $routeProvider.when('/test.php/:path',{
    template : function () {
      return "<div>Inside page</div>";
    }
  });

  $locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true, requireBase: true});
});
```

I've seen this issue on GitHub:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10536

That says that "it's a feature, not a bug". But the thing is that on production website, it sometimes fires and sometimes not (especially in safari and mobile browsers).

For example, when I make the template load slower:

```
$routeProvider.when('/test.php',{
    template : function () {
      return "<div>Welcome to test page</div>";
    },
    resolve: {
      message: function ($timeout, $q) {
        console.log('asdasa')
        return $q(function(resolve){
          $timeout(function () {
            resolve('message');
          },1000);
        });
      }
    }
  });
  $routeProvider.when('/test.php/:path',{
    template : function () {
      return "<div>Inside page</div>";
    },
    resolve: {
      message: function ($timeout, $q) {
        return $q(function(resolve){
          $timeout(function () {
            resolve('message');
          },1000);
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

Or with PHP:

```
sleep(1)
```

the enter event fires, but maybe when it is in the cache or when browser gets it quickly, it does not.

There are a couple of hacks on github but I'm not a big fan of quick hacks because of their reliability.

For example this dirty hack mentioned on github doesn't work any more:

```
$rootElement.data("$$ngAnimateState").running = false;
```

I also tried:

```
app.run(function($animate) {
  $animate.enabled(true);
});
```

But it has a very strange behavior and in safari it doesn't help.

Here is a [JSBIN EXAMPLE](http://jsbin.com/yifunodota/edit?html,js,output)

Thanks in advance and I'll be waiting for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a few days of discussion on [github](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/15589#issuecomment-272429349), we found a solution:

At first we must enable the animation on app.run (which is disabled by default). Then depending on our case, we should disable animation on body, and enable it directly on the view. But as long as we can't enable animations on the [ng-view] element, because we can't get hold of the newly created node before $animate does, we should wrap [ng-view] element in a container div.

HTML:

```
<div id="view-container">
   <div class="view" ng-view></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
app.run(function($animate) {
  $animate.enabled(true);
  $animate.enabled(document.body, false);
  $animate.enabled(document.getElementById('view-container'), true);
});
```

But this is not enough, as angular checks document.hidden and while it is true, $animation does not work. So we must override the angular function so that $animation works always (though it may be a bit dangerous for animation smoothness):

```
app.value('$$isDocumentHidden', function() { return false; });
```

That's it! Hope somebody will find it useful!